# Final Fantasy 7 Remake - Where does it end?

Tags: final-fantasy-7-remake

Keeping it as spoiler free as possible: Where does the Final Fantasy 7 Remake (Part 1) end?

Compared to the original version, is it at about one third of the story? About half?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The remake ends at the point where you leave Midgar, which happens very much like it does in the original. There are however quite significant story changes towards the end, including a final boss (or 2) that wasnt in the original. Which makes sense considering its the end of a full game and needs to have a climax or some sort.

Regarding how much of the "complete remake" this comprises... who knows. Part 1 shows how much the are willing to change or "pad out", so they could really drag this out if they wanted to.

Comment: Wasnt leaving midgard pretty much the end of Disk 1 in the original?

Comment: @Fredy31 I don't think so. It's been a long time since I've played, but I believe Disc 1 in the original ends in the Forgotten Capital - along with a major turn over of events

Comment: @Fredy31. As said, there is a LOT more after leaving Midgar before disc 1 is finished with. You can visit most of the world map before you finish disc 1 in the original.

Comment: Yeah the bottom of the question, even if I shielded it because it is not known for sure how much there would be at the end, was 'how much parts do you think the FF7 Remake will be'. Really I would like to play but dont want to play Part 1, and then have to wait a year for the next part and a total of 10 years to get the ending (See Kingdom Hearts :p). So I'm trying to wait out when it will be complete they will probably do a collection with all the parts together.

Comment: @Fredy31 If I had to guess I would say 3 parts, not just because of the original having 3 disks but because 3 = start, middle, end. However, and I doubt many will agree with me, I have a gut feeling they won't ever finish it. I dont think this remake has been as successful as they expected. Corners will be cut!

Comment: Oh and I would guess 3-4 years and all parts will have been released. Keep in mind that even though they may do an "all part collection", they will always be individual games. They won't make a seamless all-in-one game.

Comment: Yeah, thats what is stopping me right now. It took them 12 years to do the 1st part. I know most things are now in place to churn the rest of the game but damn, still took them a while to release KH3. Square doesn't have the greatest reputation in getting stuff out in a timely manner.

Answer (score 2):

The remake does not cover half, or even one third, of the original story. According to [IGN](https://www.ign.com/articles/no-final-fantasy-7-remake-is-not-the-full-game-so-wheres-the-rest-of-it):

> only about 5-6 hours into what is generally a 40-50 hour RPG.
>
> That means Remake covers about 10-15% of the full game.

Comment: From the same link, it also says "[..] Square Enix hasn’t given an exact number of games that will be in the Remake series [..]". So part 1 being only 10-15% of the story is just speculation

Comment: Correct. The estimate was made based on how many hours of the original the remake covers vs. how many hours it takes to get through the original. I thought the quote in my answer made that clear. If not, please let me know and I can update my post. Thanks

Comment: Getting out of Midgard was only 6 hours ? I could have sworn it was much longer ...